# Conditional user-agent check needs to become dry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, user-agent

I just wrote this conditional to  a different social area if the client is on ie7 (barf); because two of our social networks no longer properly support ie7 (pinterest/google plus).

I'd like to move the user agent check out of the partial into something that's cleaner and more human readable.  I tried moving the condition to a method named is_this_ie7? in both a helper and controller and both are giving me a undefined method breaks.

Where would this go if I was a more experience RoR Developer? Thanks in advance!!!!

```
      <!-- if ie7 load seperate helper  since gplus dones't support -->
    <%   if  request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /msie 7.0/i %>
          <%= share_area_for_bidding_ie7   %>
    <%   else %>
        <!-- if any other browser load main share area -->
        <%= share_area_for_bidding  %>
    <%   end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to keep browser sniffing client-side. But if you really have to do it in a Rails template, you can make a helper:

**_social.html.erb**

```
<% if ie7?(request) %>
  do ie7 stuff
<% else %>
  do other stuff
<% end %>
```

**application_helper.rb**

```
def ie7?(request)
  if request.user_agent
    !!request.user_agent.match(/msie 7.0/i)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is what I was most interested in.  Editid your post to add (request ) in the view.  If  I ever use this again I'll put it in the model. THANKS EVERYONE!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. By the way, `request` will actually be available even if you don't pass it in as an argument from the view, but it would be considered bad practice to do so (as you'd be relying on a variable that might not be there depending on where the module is included).

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I got a "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)" and that's why I piped it in as an argument.  Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, that's just because I accidentally left off the argument in the view. My point was that you can leave off the argument all together, but you shouldn't, so you can just ignore me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Typically in a helper, and if you want to be flexible for TDD, you can make a method for the string and for the request:

```
# ./app/helpers/application_helper.rb

def agent_ie7?(agent)
  agent =~ /msie 7.0/i
end

def request_ie7? 
  agent_ie7?(request.env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
end
```

A more-powerful answer is model it:

```
# ./app/models/browser.rb

class Browser

  def initialize(agent)
    @agent = agent
  end

  def ie7?
    @agent =~ /msie 7.0/i
  end

end
```

A great answer is to use an existing gem that provides what you want: https://github.com/fnando/browser

```
 gem install browser
 ...
 browser.ie7?
```

Comment: Cool solution, definitely the way to go if you plan on doing a lot of conditional stuff based on the browser. Add a `before_filter` to `ApplicationController` to do something like: `@browser = Browser.new(request)`, and then update Browser's `initialize` to take the relevant parts of the `request` object and turn them into attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should be fine in a layout. You already have most of the logic abstracted into functions already. Having it in a layout can allow you render this layout from the controller.

This may also be in a view file but you would have to copy this same code for multiple view files if you need it in more than one page. OR insert it into the needed pages using `content_for`

Comment: True.  I was most interested in a method for the conditional check because it's not as literal as it should be.